# Process doesn't die after cmd.Process.Kill() call

Tags: go

I've a program that tracks file change and should restart a specified process on file change.

I use `cmd.Process.Kill()` to kill previous process but it keeps alive after `Kill()` called.

Some piece of code related to process start from project:

```golang
// ShellPlugin allows to run shell commands in task runner 
type ShellPlugin struct {
    scope  *scope.Scope
    params Params
    log    logging.Logger
    done chan bool
}

// Call calls a plugin
func (p *ShellPlugin) Call(tx *job.RunContext, r plugins.JobRunner) (err error) {
    defer close(p.done)

    // process: /bin/sh -c ping google.com
    cmd, err := p.params.createProcess(p.scope)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to create process to execute command '%s': %s", p.params.Command, err)
    }

    p.log.Debug("command: '%s'", p.params.Command)
    p.log.Debug(`starting process "%s"...`, strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "))

    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf(`failed to execute command "%s": %s`, strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "), err)
    }

    go func() {
        select {
        case <- p.done:
            p.log.Debug("received stop signal")
            if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
                p.log.Warn("kill: %s", err.Error())
            }
            p.log.Debug("Killed")
        }
    }()

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        return formatExitError(err)
    }

    p.log.Debug("done")
    return nil
}

// Cancel called when task should be canceled
func (p *ShellPlugin) Cancel(ctx *job.RunContext) error {
    p.done <- true
    return nil
}
```

`Call()` starts job and `Cancel()` cancel it.
Both called in separate goroutine.

Full source code is [here](https://github.com/x1unix/gilbert/blob/feat/async/plugins/builtin/shell/plugin.go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the main process `sh` was killed but child process `sleep` was still alive.

The solution was to assign process group to the main process and kill a whole process group.

```
// assign process group
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

// Kill pg
syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
```

Solution was found [here](https://medium.com/@felixge/killing-a-child-process-and-all-of-its-children-in-go-54079af94773)